# Angular 10 - Guard unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I need an advice how to test Guards with some logic like, because I am a little bit confused, how to use mocks/spies in Jasmine/Karma:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegistrationGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private credentials: CredentialsService,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        return this.credentials.getAuthorities().then(() => {
            if (!this.credentials.isGuestOrAdmin()) {
                this.router.navigate(['/sign-in'], {state: {url: routerState.url}});
            }
            return this.credentials.isGuestOrAdmin();
        });
    }
}
```

and this is service:

```
export class CredentialsService {
    authenticated: boolean = false;
    authorities: UserRole[];

    constructor(private router: Router,
                private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                private authorizationService: AuthorizationService,
                private notificationService: NotificationService) {
        this.getAuthorities().then();
    }

    public async getAuthorities() {
        await this.authorizationService.getAuthorities()
            .pipe(
                map(authorities => authorities.map(element => UserRole.getUserRoleType(element)))
            )
            .toPromise()
            .then(result => {
                this.authorities = result;
                this.authenticated = this.isNotAnonymous();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.authorities = [UserRole.ANONYMOUS];
                this.authenticated = this.isNotAnonymous();
            })
    }
}
```

Is it any possibility to mock services? I tried many things with using TestBed.inject() but without success.

Version of software:

- Angular 10.1.0,
- Jasmine Core 3.6.0,
- Karma 5.2.1

Comment: Have you read Angular's testing docs? They cover a lot of different cases, including injecting test doubles: https://angular.io/guide/testing. If you have a specific problem, please give a [mre] with a better description of the issue than *"without success"*.

Comment: Yeah, i read it but the problem is that I have specific case with `canActivate` method's body

Comment: Then give a MRE of that specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do unit test it is a good thing to mock all the services you inject as you want to *unit* test. Services should be tested separately from all other components. As you mock the services you have full control over what the services' methods return.

In the providers of your TestBed you should have:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: CredentialService,
    useValue: {
      getAuthorities: () => /* here what you want the getAuthorities method to return (apparently a promise) */,
      isGuestOrAdmin: () => /* true or false */
  }
]
```

If within a test you need to change what the methods defined in the *useValue* return you can spy on those properties with

```
spyOn(TestBed.get(CredentialService), 'isGuestOrAdmin').and.returnValue(false);
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was solution!